# can I use curl as a proxy server and will it use my bandwidth?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I'm pretty sure there's a way to use curl in php to make a proxy server so my question is more, will that use my bandwidth?  if there is a way to have it not use my bandwidth how would that look?

Comment: What's wrong with a normal proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data transfer eats your bandwidth. So, you are out of luck.

The only possiblity is to strip redundant stuff and compress everything going through - this might save up to 50% of the bandwidth.

Comment: that's what I thought.  there really isn't anyway around using files off another server but making it looked like it came from yours, right?

Comment: Nope. You may just offload part of stuff to other subdomain with different IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question.

Even if you are connecting via a proxy server, your bandwidth **will** be used. It is just that the server at the other end will have no idea about the IP address (or other details) of your system (it will have the details of the proxy instead).